# Convergence in measure does not imply convergence a.e.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider
[image]

I understand the example without the existance part. In particular, how do we know that such $A_n$ exist? I was trying to play around with the $(0,1)$ interval but this looks fruitless.  Next I thought that I can just consider all over $\mathbb R$ with the Lebesgue measure with some density, say $\frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$. Then let
\begin{align*}
 A_n = [n, n + \gamma_n ]
\end{align*}
where $\gamma _n$ is such that
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{n} = \int_{n}^{n + \gamma_n} \frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi }} dx
\end{align*}
I think this works but I am not sure. This seems far too involved. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you have no problem with the existence of a probability space modelling the [infinite sequence of independent coin tosses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768863/confusion-about-probability-space-associated-with-infinite-coin-flips), you will be able to consider the existence of an infinite sequence of independent unfair coin tosses, each with its own probability of heads.

Comment: It is advisable  to study Kolmogorov's consistency/existence Theorem.